# defining variable in php based on output from php script

Tags: php, variables

I have a php script in which I am trying to define a variable based on the output from another php script.

I tried doing this:

```
$var=system("php test.php");
echo "variable is $var"
```

where test.php is the following:

```
<?php
   echo "test\n";
?>
```

As a result I expect the variable $var to have the value test.  Now when I run php script I get the following output:

```
test
variable is test
```

How can I tweak the above code so that I just have the sentence "variable is test"?

Comment: If the 2 files are on the same computer, why not use `include("test.php");`  where test.php contains  `<?php $var = 'test';?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$lastLine=exec("php test.php",$allLines,$returnValue);
```

Then you can use $lastLine or $allLines[0] for 'test'; $returnValue can be used for error checking.

system has the same second argument, but it prints the output to the screen and only returns the last line of the program.